# Fast way to convert directed to undirected graph (array of lists) in python?

Tags: python, list, graph, data-visualization

I'm trying to convert a set of arcs to a set of edges for some simple visualization work.

my arc data currently looks like:

```
(
  ['A','B',2],
  ['B','A',3],
  ['A','C',4],
  ['B','C',2],
)
```

I need to convert it to edges, so the directions are combined, looking like this:

```
(
  ['A','B',5],
  ['A','C',4],
  ['B','C',2],
)
```

I'm thinking there should be a very pythonic way to do this, but not sure what the most elegant way is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an approach using a dictionary where the keys are the ends of the arc in sorted order:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
for n1, n2, v in arcdata:
    d[min(n1, n2), max(n1, n2)] += v
result = [[k[0], k[1], v] for k, v in d.iteritems()]
```

Comment: +1 And for even more fun (and scalability w.r.t. number of ns), use advanced iterable unpacking: `for *ns, v in arcdata: d[tuple(sorted(ns))] += v`.